# web service and Triple DES Algorithm in .NET

Tags: web-services, encryption

I am making a web service that the data has to be Encrypted, I have it working with a string but the device that are going to be pulling the data from the web server will be looking for something that is xml base. I try a dataset that is the correct format but still the Triple DES function will only take a string.

Let me know if there is anyway to Encrypted a dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the clients of your web service understand the WS-Security protocols? If so, then create the service in WCF, implement message security, and it should "just work".

Answer (score 3):

Serialize the dataset and use the [TripleDES class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx), which does encryption on byte-arrays.